# Translating objective function and constraints into code

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-science, scipy-optimize

With no luck I have been trying to solve a problem within a personal project for a few weeks now. Recently I have received help from the math stack exchange in the form of the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4089367/907708 and I am now trying to translate the equations in the answer into python code and I keep getting stuck.

I will restate the question here for ease of access (I tried to post the answer but the formatting was all wacky so you'll have to refer to the link to the above answer to find it. oops)

***Question:***

**Situation:** I am trying to minimize the standard deviation between a series of points of differing heights in a list with the constraint that each point in the list can be raised anywhere from 0 to 2 units in order to minimize the standard deviation between points.

**Example:** I have a list of points which are equidistant on the x axis but not the y axis.

`h = [20, 24, 28, 24 ,20 ,18, 20, 32 ,30, 28, 20 ,24]`

Where each number in the list represents that point's height.

I also have the constraint that each point in the list can be raised by a c value anywhere from 0 to 2 in order to help achieve a smaller standard deviation.

I am trying to create an algorithm that does the optimization of minimizing the standard deviation of the points of h with the constraint that each point in h can be raised by `0 <= c <= n` for an `h` of any length with any values and with any `n > 0`

I am very new to optimization problems and although I have seen problems that look similar to my question, I have not seen any that I've been able to gather enough information to help push me further towards an answer.

If possible, I was hoping someone would help me define the objective function, constraints, and other necessary functions that would lead me to an answer.

This is not a homework problem so therefore I have no course material to help guide me to an answer. The only guidance I have is from the comments and answers to this post. Please understand that I am in no way a mathematician so I really need all the help I can get. Thanks!

***End Question:***

I have looked into countless `scipy.optimize` examples to try to figure out how to format my code to make this work but I have been unsuccessful so far. I was hoping someone with more knowledge on the subject could help me translate these formulas or tell me what libraries or material I should look into in order to help answer this question. (I would post the collection of code snippets I have tried so far but none of them got me anywhere of value any I don't think they would provide any valuable insights in order to answer the question so I purposefully omitted them)

Any feedback is greatly appreciated and I will be sure to respond quickly to any questions or comments you have. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can install [PyGad](https://pypi.org/project/pygad/). Genetic algorithms works great for this kind of optimization problems. Also, it's much easier to implement, imho. Just do `pip install pygad`. Below is the code to solve your problem. I'm using the default config of PyGad. The fitness function evaluates how good any candidate solution is. Since PyGad tries to maximize (and we want to minimize), we return `1/evaluation` in the fitness function. We can set constraints by just returning `-100` (bad fitness) for any invalid candidate solution. I plugged the formula given on the math stack solution and pre-compute `x_bar`, even though it should take less than 5 seconds. The problem specific configuration is: the `fitness_func`, `num_genes` and a initial guess for `ci` values (`init_range_low/high`).

```
import pygad
import numpy as np


X = [20, 24, 28, 24 ,20 ,18, 20, 32 ,30, 28, 20 ,24]
X_BAR = np.array(X).sum()/len(X)

def fitness_function(solution, solution_idx):
    c_bar = np.array(solution).sum()/len(solution)
    accum = 0
    for i, ci in enumerate(solution):
        if ci < 0 or ci > 2:
            return -100
        accum += (X[i] + ci - (X_BAR + c_bar))**2
    fitness = 1/accum
    return fitness


ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=100,
                       num_parents_mating=7,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=50,
                       num_genes=len(X),
                       init_range_low=0,
                       init_range_high=2,
                       parent_selection_type="sss",
                       keep_parents=7,
                       crossover_type="single_point",
                       mutation_type="random",
                       mutation_percent_genes=10)

ga_instance.run()
ga_instance.plot_result()

sol, sol_fitness, sol_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
print("Parameters of the best solution : {solution}".format(solution=sol))
```

Here is how the fitness evolves:

[image]

Finally, the solution given by the algorithm is:

```
[1.99574728e+00 1.00786156e+00 2.17545152e-02 1.16404525e+00
 1.98465204e+00 1.98997128e+00 1.98167328e+00 1.32911147e-02
 1.17406735e-03 1.30281600e-04 1.99916130e+00 1.17383310e+00]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I was wondering if you can explain what the solution given to the algorithm means as my knowledge with genetic algorithms is severely lacking. Also, I was wondering if there was any way I could tell how high each point needed to be raised from your solution? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x = np.array([20, 24, 28, 24 ,20 ,18, 20, 32 ,30, 28, 20 ,24])

# define the objective to minimize 
# (here c is the variable and x is a additional argument)
def obj(c, x): return np.sum((x+c -(np.mean(x) + np.mean(c)))**2)

# Variable bounds: 0 <= ci <= 2
bounds = [(0, 2) for _ in range(len(x))]

# initial guess for the solver
c0 = np.ones_like(x)

# call the solver and pass a function that only depends on the variable c
res = minimize(lambda c: obj(c, x), x0=c0, bounds=bounds)

# your solution
print(res.x)
```

gives

```py
array([2.        , 1.11111256, 0.        , 1.11111256, 2.        ,
       2.        , 2.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       2.        , 1.11111446])
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really like this answer! I was wondering if you knew of any way I could verify if this result is optimal. If not I still really appreciate it! Thanks again!

Comment: For this purpose, you can check `res.message`. The optimizer found a point where the norm of the gradient is below a given tolerance, so it's a local minimizer. Since your problem is convex, each local minimizer is a global one. Thus, there's no better solution.